# Changing pages with React hooks (Resets itself)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to control what question is displayed in a function that acts as a long form using Hooks. I am using use and setState. The first two pages work with no problem but then on the third click the third page ends up flashing on the screen for a second and the program goes back to 0. I don't understand what is causing this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Form.css';
function Form() {
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

if (page === 0 ){
return (
  <div>
    <p>{page}</p>
      <h1> Hello, I am Adiona.</h1>
      <p>You clicked {page} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>
       Click me
      </button>
  </div>
 );
};

if (page === 1 ){
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{page}</p>
      <h1 >Welcome to Adiona. Fill out this section to create your account.</h1>
      <form class = 'Initial'>
      <input id = 'First Name' placeHolder='First Name' type = 'text' onChange={(e)=>setFirstName(e)}/>
      <input id = 'Last Name' placeHolder='Last Name' type = 'text' onChange={(e)=>setLastName(e)}/>
      <input id = 'Email' placeHolder='Email' type = 'text' onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e)}/>
      <input id = 'Password' placeHolder='Password' type = 'text' onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e)}/>
         <button value = 'Back' onClick={() => setPage(prevPage => prevPage - 1)}>
         Back
         </button>
         <p>You clicked {page} times</p>
         <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>
           Click me
         </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

if (page === 2) {
  return(
    <div>
    <h1> hello </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

};
export default Form
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because your `page===2` displays a form, and when you click the `button` elements the form get submitted (*they default to submit buttons*).

Add `type="button"` to the `button` elements and it should get fixed.

```
  <button
    value="Back"
    onClick={() => setPage(prevPage => prevPage - 1)}
    type="button"
  >
    Back
  </button>
  <p>You clicked {page} times</p>
  <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)} type="button">
    Click me
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Don't forget to set button type to `type="button"` because otherwise, the type will be equal to "submit." It is be the reason why your website is reloading.

---

Side note:

When changing state based on previous value, always use functional updates because otherwise you are relying on unexpected behavior (race conditions, timing etc):

```
<button onClick={() => setPage(p => p + 1)} type="button">
  Click me
</button>
```

The code above will ensure that pages always increment based on the latest value. If you want to read about it more, check out the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).